# JMeter : How to handle asynchronous http post request

Tags: rest, http, automation, jmeter

I'm trying to automate a POST call where I'm getting multiple responses every 5 seconds.

For example, while uploading a file,

file read......200 OK

Uploading Started.....200 OK

Uploaded......200 OK

And after certain time, when the process is complete on the server side, I get a response saying "Finished Successfully...200 OK".

But in JMeter, connection is closed when first 200 is received.
How can I wait for all the responses conditionally and exit when the desired response is received by the request?

Comment: See also https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) and  develop a custom org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerClient class.

You can use http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ for the HTTP Client library, but ensure you use the same as JMeter.